# bcrypt returning wrong calulation

Tags: php, bcrypt

I am new to bcrypt this is my testing code that returns the hashed password

```
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errPassword) {
require "libs/password.php";

        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); //password_compat function
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
  $result = "$name\n$hash\n$email";
} else {

    echo "didnt work";
}}
```

when i validate it at https://www.dailycred.com/blog/12/bcrypt-calculator it doesn't match example password '1234' returns     $2y$10$Wz/1MRBMFauEtGdJNeaKq.5INBmig0Nip2urekRON8ekLkYesdj6i 
and when i validate it by dailycred i get Invalid salt revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that PHP library uses new "2y" prefix.

It was used in this and some other libraries because the original code, with "2a" prefix, had a bug and there was a need to distinguish old and new, secure, codes.

So just simply replace 2y with 2a.

Comment: if 2y is invalid why does it pass the first test? if it is then where did it go wrong?, why should i use a insecure vulnerable prefix, i want to know where i'm wrong not how to cheat the system

Comment: You aren't wrong at all. Prefix itself does nothing, completely nothing. It just shows to user/computer what hash function was used. "2a" is original prefix for bcrypt, but PHP library had a bug and they made a fix. To help coders, they introduced "2y" prefix - it just shows that secure version is used. Libraries for language that is being used at this website, probably, haven't got the bug and stayed on the default "2a" prefix.